# If you write a useful app... does writing it in Rails give you an advantage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

This is something I've been wondering for a bit.

If you were to write a successful site/app, would writing it in rails give you and advantage, say for getting the app noticed, as opposed to writing it in PHP etc?

Do people/companies who write in ruby/rails actively promote that their site/app is written in rails so it gets more publicity/hype?

Appreciate any feedback/POV's.

Comment: If your site is successful, nobody cares if it was built with lego bricks.

Comment: A site built in Lego bricks would probably draw some visitors by its sheer awesomeness.

Comment: Goddam, I was under the impression that if u used RoR and u developed something cool the sh*t just hit the fan cos it got promoted in the RoR forums/communities... What is this Lego Bricks framework? Eh? Come on... whats the git repo :)

Comment: @Thilo, "If your site is successful, nobody cares if it was built with lego bricks.". The Lego people would care. They'd worship you.

Answer (score 4):

Not much.  People don't look under the covers.  The advantage is that you can build it faster and change it faster, which means you get to market faster.

Comment: Also, Rails is also about a set of best practices coming together very well. An important one being testing - that's a very good habit to get into and Rails makes it easy to get started with it.

Comment: Huh.... not the answers I was expecting...! Shocked I is... I was under the impression that when you built a RoR app that did something cool it would get more hype/startup interest than it's PHP brother...

Comment: Yeah, the RoR people would like you to believe that too.  But can you name any really successful sites and the technology under them?

Answer (score 0):

Though some companies mention that the app runs on Rails or built in NYC, regular users, as a rule, do not care  what the app they are using is built upon. But if you plan to  eventually sell it  or draw the investments, the trendy technology will certainly give you some bonus points.